# Android messaging between thread (in a class) and activty

Tags: java, android, multithreading, messaging, handler

How can i send a message between an activity and a thread if put the thread in a class?

Okay, here is a little more detailed code:

```
public class AnActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Callback
{

    Button          b           = null;
    TextView        t           = null;
    MyThread        mThread     = null;
    public Handler  mainHandler = new Handler( this );

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        b = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.buttonSEND );

        b.setOnClickListener( this );
        mThread = new MyThread( this );
        mThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick( View v )
    {
        Message m = Message.obtain();
        m.what = 4;
        mThread.myThreadHandler.sendMessage( m );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage( Message msg )
    {
        Toast.makeText( this, "What= " + Integer.toString( msg.what ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The following class is not a part of AnActivity

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public Handler myThreadHandler;
    Activity mainActivity;

    public MyThread ( AnActivity anActivity )
    {
        this.mainActivity = anActivity;     
    }


    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        myThreadHandler = new Handler()
        {
            // sending back a message immediately after a received one
            public void handleMessage( Message msg )
            {
                Message m = Message.obtain();
                m.what = 10;
                // MY PROBLEM:
                // mainActivity.mainHandler.sendMessage( m ); // mainHandler is not visible
                // mainActivity.sendMessage( m ); // does not working
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my Activity:

```
public class AnActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Callback
{

    Button          b           = null;
    TextView        t           = null;
    MyThread        mThread     = null;
    public Handler  mainHandler = new Handler( this );


    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        b = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.buttonSEND );

        b.setOnClickListener( this );
        mThread = new MyThread( this );
        mThread.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick( View v )
    {
        Message m = Message.obtain();
        m.what = 4;
        mThread.myThreadHandler.sendMessage( m );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage( Message msg )
    {
        Toast.makeText( this, "This is AnActivity. What=" + Integer.toString( msg.what ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Modified thread:
In the constructor i can store UI thread's messagehandler.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    public Handler  myThreadHandler;
    Activity        mainActivity;
    Handler         mainHandler;
    int             what    = -1;


    public MyThread ( AnActivity anActivity )
    {
        this.mainActivity = anActivity;
        this.mainHandler = anActivity.mainHandler;
    }


    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        myThreadHandler = new Handler()
        {
            public void handleMessage( Message msg )
            {
                what = msg.what;


                // Writing back to main UI thread
                mainActivity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Toast.makeText( mainActivity, "This is MyThread. What=" + Integer.toString( what ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    }
                } );

                Message m = Message.obtain();
                m.what = 10;
                mainHandler.obtainMessage( 12 ).sendToTarget();
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for the "Dialog" box thereby you can show Alert message, confirmation message, etc. to the user.

For more info, refer this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html ,

Here a good example on Alert Dialog box: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-alertdialog-example/ .

From your commented code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();     
alt_bld.setMessage("apprika target achieve...");
alt_bld.setCancelable(false);
alt_bld.setPositiveButton("yes", new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub } });
alt_bld.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub dialog.cancel(); } }); 
alert.show();
```

put that code in in any method any just call by passing the parameter. at the running thread or in the activity.

try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a constructor in the class where you will give the instance of the activity. like so:

```
public ConnectClass(Activity ac) {
    activity = ac;
}
```

In this case you would need to add a class variable in the thread class named activity.

Comment: sounds good. when i got the activity, how can i obtain a message from "activity"?

Comment: you can make a method in the activity and call it from the thread with the following: "activity.theMethodName("maybe a string?");" or something like that.

Comment: or you could make a variable in the activity and fill it by doing this: "activity.theVariable = "the string u need";".

Comment: well, but it is not exactly what i need. i would like to send a message to the message handler in the activity from the thread class.